# How to install apache river on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache

I have a class where we have to use apache river for our work and assignment and I’m trying to install it at home.

I'm fairly new to apache-river and I have installed plug-ins for eclipse before, but this seems a bit more tricky or maybe I'm doing it wrong.

I've looked at https://river.apache.org/ and I've downloaded the zip file and extracted it but I’m not sure what to do with it after that. I'm not even sure that, that is the right download I need.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct me if I misunderstood your question. 
I believe you want to import whatever it is Apache River has to offer in Eclipse such that you can use classes in Apache River in your project. Correct?

If yes, this is what i did -

1. Downloaded apache-river2.2.2.bin.zip from the site you mentioned, extracted it.
2. Created new Java Project in Eclipse with a trial class.
3. Configured build path of this Eclipse project, and added all the jars from the /lib folder as 'External Jars'. 
   All these jars showed up in the Referenced Libraries section in my project in Eclipse.
4. I tried a sample line of code to see if I get classes from Apache river. 
   for eg -

   ```
      LookupLocator locator = new LookupLocator(arg0);
   ```

   And it worked - Eclipse added

   ```
      import net.jini.core.discovery.LookupLocator;
   ```

   automatically.
5. I checked and this class comes from the jini-core.jar

Of course, if you are using other build / dependency management tools like maven/ant, this eclipse process will differ a little bit. 
Let me know if this worked for you.